# how to get tell() to work

Tags: python, python-2.7

I'm trying to open a file and read from the last point read. My files are rather big (20 Mb to ~ 1 Gb) After doing some research it seems that tell() and seek() would be one of the most efficient ways to perform this. I've tried the following code

```
opened = open(filename, "rU")   
f1 = csv.reader(opened)
k = []
for line in f1:
    k.append(opened.tell())
```

When I do this every value in the list is 8272 Long. Does that mean that I cannot use this implementation? Is there something I'm missing? Thanks for your help!

I'm running python 2.7 in Windows 7

**Update**

After piecing together everything learned here and trial and error I get the following code

```
opened = open(filename, "rU")   
k = [0]
where = 1
for switch in opened:
    where += len(switch) + 1
    f = StringIO.StringIO(switch)
    interesting = csv.reader(f, delimiter=',')
    good_values = interesting.next()
    k.append(where)

return k
```

This allows the user to know exactly where in the file to go to while still being able to parse it according to its format. I'm not completely sure of why the offsets need to be constantly added (It seems that the newline is not accurately accounted for in len()).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like the `csv.reader` is reading the file in chunks of 8272 bytes, that's why you see this number returned from `opened.tell()` many times - until, I guess, you have read all the lines from your file in the range of 0-8272. After that you will see 8272*2 a few times, exact number will depend on the length of the lines in the buffer read.

So, basically, in your program, `tell()` doesn't give you offsets of new CSV lines, as you seem to assume. It's only telling you about offset of the end of the file's region currently read into an internal OS buffer used by system functions used to implement the Python's IO functions.

Comment: So I iterated over "opened" and added up the lengths of the strings. This gave the correct value. I still would like to use csv reader because that is the format of the file I'm reading. I'm using a comprehension to implement it. 

Is that more efficient than using regular expressions? Is there a more efficient way to tackle this problem? T

Comment: Not sure what you do 'by comprehension'. If you have a method to calculate offset of a given line correctly why won't you do opened.seek to the offset of the file just after your last processed csv line on restart, and then pass opened to the csv.reader constructor? That should work. I don't recommend regular expressions for processing big csv files.

Comment: The problem is any use of csv reader complicates things. I'm trying to parse the file according to csv format, but in order to get an accurate count of location I have to add up all of the characters. I will periodically reading the file for any new changes which is why i want to seek where the file leaves off. Is it better to do a running count or to leave each line as a raw input and then to process it according to csv format?

Comment: well, in this case I would just save somewhere the size of the file (obtained from os.path.getsize) at the time of processing. Can another process append to the file while you read it?

Comment: Using regular expressions or string.split is not recommended in general, but in your specific case, if the data is particularly simple (no string fields with, potentially, your field delimiter in them) it may be a way to go...